# How to move AmazonDrive data over to S3 Glacier?

Tags: amazon-glacier, amazon-cloud-drive

Since Amazon changed their price of unlimited cloud storage in AmazonDrive, I now have to shut down my use of AmazonDrive. It's just too expensive. I'm looking to move my storage needs over to Glacier.

Is there a way that I can move my entire AmazonDrive storage directly to S3 Glacier?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.  Amazon Drive is a consumer service that appears to have been built using AWS components, but is not part of the AWS product.  The Amazon Drive API is invitation-only, so it isn't possible to write your own code to programmatically transfer content without proposing to build an Amazon Drive app, and having your proposal accepted.

You will need to download your content and upload it to S3, using the Standard storage class, then create a bucket lifecycle policy to migrate the objects into the Glacier storage class.  S3 does not support directly uploading objects to the Glacier class -- they can only be migrated via object lifecycle.